# Process memory not freeing up after JSON serialization in python3

Tags: python, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, python-multiprocessing

I am writing a program that takes in a dataset of photo-paths and returns a dataset of each of the photos with a cropped image (containing only the face in the photo) as a 1D tensor.

The problem is the dataset is 500,000 images. So I cant create a dataset of 500,000 images as arrays and then serialize it because I would run out of RAM. As a result, after every 1000 (50 for testing purposes) images, I am serializing the dataset so far and then continuing. I am using the method below. Also, a side note is that I am running this method simultaneously on different datasets using Multiprocessing.

Despite all this hassle, my RAM memory is not freeing up at all. In fact, the amount of memory each of my processes takes is increasing the further I get into my dataset.

```
def get_data_file(dataset, thread_num):
    detector = FaceRecognizer()
    temp_dataset = []
    ctr = 0
    file_ctr = 0
    gc.collect()

    while len(dataset) > 0:
        datum = dataset.pop(0)
        print("File ", thread_num, file_ctr, "datapoint", ctr)
        detector.new_image(datum['path'])
        try:
            a = detector.get_face_1D_numpy().tolist()
            datum["as_tensor"] = a
            datum["landmarks"] = detector.get_facial_landmarks(thread_num)
            temp_dataset.append(datum)
            gc.collect()
        except (LookupError, AssertionError, NameError, FileNotFoundError) as e:
            gc.collect()
            pass

        if ctr >= 50:
            file_name = 'FinalDataset/FinalDataset' + str(thread_num) + "t_" + str(file_ctr)+ "f_" + '.json'
            file_ctr += 1
            ctr = 0
            with open(file_name, 'w') as outfile:
                json.dump(temp_dataset, outfile)
            del(temp_dataset)
            gc.collect()
            temp_dataset = []
        else:
            ctr += 1
            gc.collect()

    file_name = 'FinalDataset/FinalDataset' + str(thread_num) + "t_" + str(file_ctr)+ "f_"+ '.json'
    file_ctr += 1
    with open(file_name, 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(temp_dataset, outfile)

    del temp_dataset
    gc.collect()
```

[My task Manager memory usage after 0 seriliazations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuSVh.png)

[My task Manager memory usage after 4 seriliazations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOLnN.png) which is much greater than at 0 serializations, even though it should be roughly the same.

Comment: just as a brute force test, have you tried adding `gc.collect()` in between every line to see if that changes your result?

Comment: @JacobIRR yes but it doesn't seem to behave any different. In fact with or without any number manual calls to gc.collect, it behaves the same way